# Editing the index page in the theme settings wordpress

Tags: wordpress

The content of the home page is in the file index.php. How can I make the contents of this file were edited in the theme settings (or elsewhere the admin panel of wordpress)?

Comment: Its better to create a page and then set as home page.

Comment: Try reduxframework they have a full documentation for all fields

Answer (score 0):

you can edit index.php in wordpress admin panel Appearance -> editor. this will open your theme files.